# Xcode type number in the power

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

How can I type a number in the power (exponentiation) in Xcode. I am creating a calculator in Xcode, but cannot make it out, how to type such functions into the buttons like x^2, x^3, x^y. The only way I can use to solve this problem is to copy-paste such symbols from google (x², xʸ etc.) But it does not seem right. In "emoji and symbols" cannot find them either. Maybe there is some hot key in Mac, Xcode, the analog to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd> in MS Word?

Comment: Are you trying to write down x^2, or are you trying to calculate x^2.

Comment: In "emoji and symbols", type "superscript" in the search box and you'll see things like `²`. Search for "small" in the search box and you'll see things like `ʸ`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use x^2, x^3, x^y, instead use `pow(x, 2)`, `pow(x,3)`, `pow(x, y)` function to calculate powers.
And the objective-c and Swift is the same function name.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help! ) Indeed, by typing "superscript" in emoji and symbols' search box did help. Some symbols printed above the line really popped up, now I can easily type into my buttons something like x², x³, xʸ, sin⁻¹ etc. But after all it's a pity that there is no hot key for that in xCode, Swift like ctrl-shift-+ in MS Word.